# Calculate the average for a range of date intervals (200k records) quickly

Tags: c#, sql, azure, bigdata, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently in a situation where I have a CosmosDB with big data. This big data consists of documents containing an object with a date and a double value.

What I'm trying to do is fetch the data for a month (which gives ~220K records) and calculate the average of the double value for each day of that month. I'm probably having horribly inefficient code right now. I'm looking for a formula or more efficient code that solves my problem. I can't think of the solution and Google searches haven't given me the solution either.

My current calculations are too slow. Preferrably I'd have the calculations done in less than a second.

This is a C# Web API we're talking about, connecting to an Azure CosmosDB. This is my current code:

```
// GET api/values/{databasename}/<Guid>
[HttpGet("{database}/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetRange(string database, string id, [FromQuery] int 
option, [FromQuery] string from, [FromQuery] string to)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(from, out var dateFrom);
        DateTime.TryParse(to, out var dateTo);
        var comparison = DateTime.Compare(dateFrom, dateTo);
        if (comparison >= 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("Given dates are incorrect.");
        }

        // Get the timespan for the given option.
        var timespan = TimeSpanSelectionHelper.GetTimeSpanForOption(option);

        var dataRange = _cosmosDbService.GetRange(database, id, from, to).ToList();
        var result = from kvp in dataRange
            let key = RoundToNearest(kvp.EventEnqueuedUtcTime, timespan)
            group kvp by key
            into grouping
            select new {
                grouping.Key,
                Avg = (int) grouping.Average(x => x.Temperature),
                Min = grouping.Min(x => x.Temperature),
                Max = grouping.Max(x => x.Temperature) 
            };

        var enumerable = result.ToArray();
        var min = enumerable.Select(x => new CosmosDbRangeSelectionKeyValueJsonModel(x.Key, x.Min)).ToArray();
        var avg = enumerable.Select(x => new CosmosDbRangeSelectionKeyValueJsonModel(x.Key, x.Avg)).ToArray();
        var max = enumerable.Select(x => new CosmosDbRangeSelectionKeyValueJsonModel(x.Key, x.Max)).ToArray();

        var model = new CosmosDbRangeSelectionJsonModel(min, avg, max);
        return Ok(model);
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException de)
    {
        var baseException = de.GetBaseException();
        var message = string.Format("{0} error occurred: {1}, Message: {2}", de.StatusCode, de.Message,
                                baseException.Message);
        return NotFound(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var baseException = e.GetBaseException();
        var message = string.Format("Error: {0}, Message: {1}", e.Message, baseException.Message);
        return NotFound(message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt"></param>
/// <param name="d"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static DateTime RoundToNearest(DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
    var delta = dt.Ticks % d.Ticks;
    // Do we round up?
    var roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;
    var offset = roundUp ? d.Ticks : 0;

    return new DateTime(dt.Ticks + offset - delta, dt.Kind);
}
```

**EDIT 03-01-2018**

We have to keep tabs on this:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions

Comment: The biggest problem is that you're returning 220k records to begin with. That's a lot of data to transfer when you're really only interested in (at most) 31 results. Apply the filtering and aggregators when querying Cosmos directly, and that will significantly improve the performance, as it won't transfer ~220k rows over the network.

Comment: I was just testing and the query for all records is already taking me 3 min. So I can confirm your statement.

Comment: Group by is unsupported. Do you have any ideas on how I could minify the result from my sql query? All I have figured out to do for now is an order and select with a where.

Comment: The point is of course that it isn't an _sql_ query, Everything after `from kvp in dataRange` is in-memory LINQ.

Comment: I have been working on new code. I seem to need the group by function.  All my LINQ/lambda expressions fail. I'm pointing out I need a group by and I'm not the only one.

Comment: Alternatively I'm thinking maybe I need to use triggers to update an average value in separate collections for each interval value (my intervals are defined). Or I need to fetch the average for each interval value, for example: I perform a network request for each day of a month.

Comment: Just throwing it out there: if you put this in a relational database you'd be fine.

Comment: I have a Stream Analytics Job that outputs IoT Hub data to the Cosmos DB. AFAIK I can't have an SQL database as an output in that Job. Hence I don't think I can use a relational database. However what you said is true.

Comment: This seems to show a way: http://gunnarpeipman.com/2016/02/beer-iot-using-stream-analytics-to-save-data-from-iot-hub-to-sql-database/ I've never done it though - just interested in how it works.